# What type of connector is this

Tags: fiber

I visit a flat and found this type of connector, the place, in theory, is capable of having fiber optic up to 1GB, I was expecting an OTN socket something like this:

[image]

Instead, I found this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about residential networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those connectors on the left are RJ45-style, then you are in a neighborhood/building with FTTB/FTTC "fibre technology". You may connect a VDSL2 or G.fast device there.

If the connectors are Fibre Optics style, then this might be a simplex LC connector. Some regions deploy FTTH - and then that's real FTTH - on a single singlemode fibre, where up/downstream light is done with different wavelengths.

For an example, see the cable examples on https://www.init7.net/en/internet/hardware/

Answer (score 0):

- Socket 1 looks like RJ-45 socket, presumably ethernet
- Socket 2 looks blanked off or is there something behind the cover
- Sockets on the right look like [Swiss mains power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Swiss_SEV_1011)

In some countries, for example the United Kingdom, what the internet company sells as "fibre broadband" is often fibre-to-the-cabinet, ie, copper-to-your-office.

Comment: That actually *is* a swiss mains connector, with the bottom left one wired to a switch somewhere in the room.

Comment: correct, is a Swiss connector but I am very curious because it looks like a RJ-45 with something blue at the end but "no copper"